# is there an odata client for azure storage

Tags: azure, odata

One that will deal with the authentication needs of azure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient code for tables is:
`CloudStorageAccount.Parse(...).CreateCloudTableClient().GetDataServiceContext()`

Answer (score 1):

I think that the CloudStorageAccount Class ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudstorageaccount_members.aspx ) is for you. the "Credentials" checks the access you need.